# Sitewide category terms

Tags: multisite, categories

I'm looking to implement standard category terms across a network of multisite blogs.

The aim is:

- create a category on one blog (or the root blog), and it is created on all blogs
- each blog will have its own category URLs e.g. with a category called 'apples' it'd be test.example.com/categories/apples and on anothertest.example.com/categories/apples - only listing those posts on the appropriate blog.

I've seen there's a concept of global_terms in the code - I'm not sure if this is related or not, as I can't find a lot of documentation on this, or whether it's deprecated in 3.0.x. If this is what I'm looking for, can anyone provide an example?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

global_terms is not only deprecated, it was never fully functional, and all it did was assign the same category id to identical terms. It didn't do what you want.

While you can create the same categories on all blogs at the time of creation using something like this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpmu-new-blog-defaults/

the part about making it on the main blog and pumping it out to existing one will take some custom coding.

Comment: Thanks, I thought global_terms wasn't what I was looking for, but good to have it confirmed.

Comment: I think I'm going to probably have to go down a replication route - finding the hooks for when a category is saved / edited / deleted, and replicating it across the sites if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: If you write or find a good way of replicating taxonomies between sister sites in a network, I'd be interested.